# The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$ diverge. What about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1) \times (n+2)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$ diverge. What about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1) \times (n+2)}$?

Comment: Limit-compare it to $\sum 1/n^2$; and note that $\sum 1/n^2$ converges (by the integral test)

Comment: since $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* $$\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac1{n+1} - \frac1{n+2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It is just 
$$=\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac14\right)+...=\frac12.$$